# python how to import from the son of the son of the parent

Tags: python, python-2.7, relative-import

I have this hierarchy:

```
myfile.py
Spider
----__init__.py
----spiders
----------------file.py
```

and the `file.py` contains class `myClass`

I used to do this **inside the myfile.py**

```
from Spider.spiders.file import myClass
```

now I changed my hierarchy, and I put `myfile.py` inside a folder named `newFolder`, so the new hierarchy is:

```
newFolder
------myfile.py
Spider
----__init__.py
----spiders
----------------file.py
```

and I changed the path as this:

```
from ... import Spider.spiders.file.myClass
```

but I got `invalid syntax` in the `spiders.spiders`

help please

Comment: The mention answer doesn't help me, please help me

Answer (score 2):

In `from <a> import <b>` syntax you should specify module path before import: `from <a>.<b> import <c>`:

```
from ...Spider.spiders.file import myClass
```

You can also add parent directory to path:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
from Spider.spiders.file import myClass
```

Comment: I got this error `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli, you should have `__init__.py` in the same folder with your `myfile.py ` (it can be empty)

Comment: I have `__init__.py` file inside the `newFolder` and i still got this error `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli how do you run the script?

Comment: as always, i run the cmd in that folder and call the script name

Comment: If you want to use relative path you should run scripts with -m parameter. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python